# Migrating UIWebView to WKWebview new evaluateJavaScript; creating a synchronous wrapper the right way

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm migrating from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` and the function to run javascript was changed from synchronous to asynchronous. I'm trying to create a wrapper to keep running js code synchronously. The reason why I don't migrate all my calls to use the new provided function is because I have over 100 calls to the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` and I really don't want to migrate the logic in all those calls to be async at this point.

I got a piece of code from another question that should in theory work but is blocking the main thread when waiting for the result from the new `evaluateJavaScript` in `WKWebView`:

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

extension WKWebView {

@objc @discardableResult func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString (string:String) -> String? {
    var finished:Bool = false
    var resultString:String?

    self.evaluateJavaScript(string, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let sResult = result as? String {
                resultString = sResult
            }
        }
        finished = true
    })

    while (!finished) {
        RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: .distantFuture)
    }
    return resultString
}
```

}

Is there another way to accomplish this? Or is this an approach I should steer clear from and just migrate everything now?

Comment: _in theory_, your code shown would not work. You should better rewrite your code in an asynchronous way.

Comment: you have to rewrite the code in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Async is the way to go; the WKWebView content handling and execution happens in a different process, hence the switch to async.